# Width plot with gnuplot

Tags: profiling, cuda, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to profile my cuda program. I found especially the width plot feature helpful. It seems however that computeprof offers no way to export or customize the plots generated. Fortunately all the data is stored in csv format so I thought I could do it just myself using gnuplot or something similar. So now to my question: I couldn't find an example to pro create a plot of time blocks can you create such a plot using gnuplot and if so how?

[image: Example of a width plot]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately horizontal `histograms`, as what this style of plot is called in gnuplot, are not easy to create. In gnuplot histograms are natively vertical. If you do however feel the need to have a horizontal histogram, check [this](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/10/turning-of-histogram.html) blog entry.

For a vertical histogram you need to do the following:
With this data file `Data.dat`:

```
A B C D E F G H I J
0.41 0.03 0.74 0.97 0.15 0.05 0.11 0.60 0.25 0.76
```

and this little gnuplot script:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set key autotitle columnheader
plot for [i=1:10] "Data.dat" using i
```

you should be able to receive the result you are looking for (however vertically ;) ). If you still feel the need for a horizontal histogram you can follow the tutorial of the blog. It is not 100% what you are looking for, but it does the vertical - horizontal trick.